# Angular 6 fullCalendar Display popover on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar in an Angular 6 application. I want to display fullcalendar popover while hovering over an event like [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo). I want to achieve this via my ts file without using jquery. Here's my code.

HTML:

```
 <section class="main-content">
  <div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
   <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar 
    [options]="calendarOptions" 
    [(eventsModel)]="events"
    (eventClick)="handleClick($event.detail.event.data)"
    (eventMouseOver)="mouseOver($event, calendarPopover)">
    </ng-fullcalendar>
   </div>
 </section>

 <ng-template #calendarPopover>
    <h3>{{toolData .title}}</h3>
  </ng-template>
```

TS File:

```
mouseOver(event, content){
    var data = event.detail.event.data;
    this.toolData = data;
    console.log(this.toolData);
  }
```

Similar to a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257220/eventmouseover-fullcalendar-angular-6-doesnt-work)

I want to get the ng-template to open up on display. I have tried ngbPopover but unlike ngbModal, ngbPopover doesn't have an open method that would simply open up the popover by calling it's method since it's a [directive](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api).

If anyone knows any solution using either the fullCalendar popover method (without jquery) or displaying via ng-template, any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Comment: fullCalendar itself doesn't have a built-in popover method. You would need to use something like Bootstrap's "popper" library or a similar thing - maybe something designed for Angular would be sensible.

Comment: Yes, I've already mentioned that. There's a bootstrap component for Angular  that I'm trying to use but it's not working, don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Ok. I was confused because you said "using either the fullCalendar popover method "...but there's no such thing

Comment: There is but only if you're using jquery. Such as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992871/fullcalendar-v2-show-popover-on-the-top-of-slot-of-weekly-view

Comment: well fullCalendar requires jQuery, so you must be running jQuery. Why do you care about not using jQuery?

Comment: I'm using ng-fullcalendar here.

Comment: It still requires jQuery to run, unless you're using the 4.x branch which is still in alpha

Answer (score 4):

I am using this solution for my Angular 10 app, with FullCalendar 5.3.
The library tippy.js was very easy to integrate and use - https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/

No extra tooltip html elements needed. Just use the fullcalendar eventDidMount render hook to add a tippy tooltip to your events:

```
import tippy from "tippy.js";
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
// create calendar and configure it

eventDidMount: (info) => {
  tippy(info.el, {
   content: 'Content to display inside tooltip',
   })
 }
}
```

If you want to display dynamic content inside your tooltip you can, for example, set it to your event's title by using

```
eventDidMount: (info) => {
  tippy(info.el, {
   content: info.event.title,
   })
 }
}
```

There is no more code needed. The tooltip is added to your event on hovering.
If you want to adjust the styling of the tooltip you can use the class .tippy-box. For example, I changed it to mostly match Angular Material's Mat-Tooltip. Just added the style to my component's .css file.

```
.tippy-box {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(97, 97, 97, .9);
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: It's great solution for Angular application. It's work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that simple by using `ng-container` and `*ngIf` or `[hidden]`

*instead using*

```
<ng-template #calendarPopover></ng-template>
```

*use*

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isHidden" #calendarPopover>...</ng-container>
```

**notice:** we used `ng-container` and we controlling it's display by `*ngIf`

*TS*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: [ '...' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  isHidden = false;
}
```

*trigger*

```
<section class="main-content">
  <div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
    <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar (mouseenter)="isHidden = !isHidden" (mouseleave)="isHidden = !isHidden" [options]="calendarOptions" [(eventsModel)]="events (eventClick)="handleClick($event.detail.event.data)" (eventMouseOver)="mouseOver($event, calendarPopover)">
    </ng-fullcalendar>
  </div>
</section>
```

**notice:** `(mouseenter)` and `mouseleave` look at the [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hover-to-show?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
This is not what I exactly want to achieve. I want popover to display on an event and the popover has to show information related to that event only. Like this: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo

Answer (score 0):

I created custom popover component with the help of ngx popover and tether.js for ng-full calendar .now popover can be shown on any elements. Now its not dependent on button only.

Here is demo url:
https://ngfullcalendarngxpopover.firebaseapp.com

Here is repo url:
https://github.com/raoshahid799/ng-full-calendar-ngx-popover[image]